# MySQL trigger no funciona desde query PHP

Tags: php, mysql, trigger

Tengo un trigger que llama a un procedimiento almacenado para insertar datos a otra tabla, si ejecuto la consulta en la consola mysql; Por ejemplo un INSERT el motor de base de datos ejecuta el trigger sin problemas y procedimiento pasa los datos a otra tabla, pero cuando lo ejecuto mediante query desde php no se ejecuta el trigger.

Realizo el mismo ejercicio de la consola, pero no entiendo por qué no se ejecuta el trigger desde query PHP.

```
    CREATE  TRIGGER after_insert AFTER INSERT ON bodega FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL calculo(NEW.cod_detalle,NEW.cod_materia_prima); /*Traspasa datos a otra tabla.*/
END;
```

- Query que ejecuto en mysql funciona y ejecuta trigger
- Query que ejecuto en php funciona, pero no ejecuta trigger

  INSERT INTO `bodega` (`cod_detalle`, `cod_bodega`, `cod_vale_entrada`, `cod_vale_salida`, `cod_vale_traslado`, `cod_materia_prima`, `cantidad`) VALUES (45156, 1, NULL, 19866, NULL, '30571001000', 1.00);

Comment: El usuario@host de php ¿tiene permisos para ejecutar el procedimiento?

Comment: Seguramente no estás con el mismo usuario (el cual tiene los permisos para ejecutar TRIGGERS) dentro de PHP, revisa tus conexiones en PHP y asegúrate que el usuario que tengas tenga los permisos necesarios (tal como el usuario que ocupas dentro de tu motor de base de datos)

Comment: Verifique el usuario@host, son los mismos y con permisos de ejecutar TRIGGERS. Aun sigue sin funcionar

Comment: La creacion del trigger y el procedimiento estan creados con el mismo usuario@host

Comment: ¿El código PHP muestra algún error en concreto?

Comment: No, solo me advierte sobre el uso de mysqli porque todo el sistema está orientado a mysql.